# ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, erb

I have a `Class City` that `has_many :clients` and a `Class Client` which `has_one :city` and `belongs_to :city`.

Now this is my Clients migration:

```
class CreateClients < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :clients do |t|
      t.string :business
      t.string :owner_or_manager
      t.string :number
      t.string :email
      t.belongs_to :city

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

And my City migration:

```
class CreateCities < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :cities do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

This is my City show.html.erb

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="col-sm-2 center-block mgntop">
        <h3><%=@city.name%></h3>
        <h3><%=@city.clients%></h3>
        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_city_path(@city), class: "btn" %>
        <%= link_to "Delete", city_path(@city), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Estas seguro que quieres borrar este cliente?"}, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see in my show.html.erb I have `<h3><%=@city.clients%></h3>` but my output is `<Client::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x007f9383434bf8>`. 
But I want to show all the Clients that have that specific City. I have done `@city.clients.name%` but my output is just the word "Client". I know I am close to get what I want, but I need some help. So, how can I show all the Clients that have that specific City?

Answer (score 0):

Since city has many clients.
You can do a .each loop and show all the records.

```
<% @city.clients.each do |client|%>

<%= client.business %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have done @city.clients.name but my output is just the word "Client"

`@city.clients` is a `ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy`, not your expected client, because `clients` is `has_many` relation in your models. Btw `@city.clients.name` will return your `class_name` actually.

Just refactor your `show.html.erb` like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">
      <div class="col-sm-2 center-block mgntop">
        <h3><%=@city.name %></h3>

        <!-- Remove <h3><%=@city.clients%></h3> -->
        <!-- Start replacing -->
        <% @city.clients.each do |client| %>
          <p><%= client.bussiness %><p>
          <p><%= client.number %><p>
          <p><%= client.email %><p>
        <% end %>
        <!-- End replacing -->

        <%= link_to "Edit", edit_city_path(@city), class: "btn" %>
        <%= link_to "Delete", city_path(@city), method: :delete, data: {confirm: "Estas seguro que quieres borrar este cliente?"}, class: "btn btn-danger" %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> want to show all the Clients that have that specific City

```
<% @city.clients.each do |client| %>
  <%= client.id %>
<% end %>
```

The problem you have is *outputting* `city.clients` means that you're going to show the "collection" for the `clients` of a `city` (IE `Client.where(city_id: @city.id)`).

You need to loop through the collection, and output each object individually.

---

> which `has_one :city` and `belongs_to :city`.

You cannot have two associations with the same name.

If you want your `client` to *own* a city, you'll have to call it a different name, else remove it from your `model` entirely:

```
#app/models/client.rb
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :city                        #-> ok
   has_one :owned_city, class_name: "City" #-> only if you have "belongs_to :client" in City model
end
```